# How to get internet to work in Android TV emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

I have an Android TV (not google TV) emulator setup running android tv 5.0 and it has no access to the internet. In settings for both wifi and ethernet it says "no connection". Is there something I am missing? I have emulators for other versions of android running on phones and everything networking wise works ok.

Also I am not saying that my app has no internet access. I am saying that the actually Android TV settings says no network connections.

Comment: The Android SDK emulator images do not emulate any particular network connection (WiFi, Ethernet, etc.), just general availability of Internet access. If you are expecting Settings to report details about a connection, you are likely to be disappointed.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. That answers it. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android SDK emulator images do not emulate any particular network connection (WiFi, Ethernet, etc.), just general availability of Internet access. This is not unique to the Android TV emulator -- all the emulator images behave this way. For most apps, this isn't a problem, as they just need Internet access. For apps that need lower-level information, you are unfortunately stuck with testing on hardware.

Note that third-party emulators, like Genymotion, may offer other alternatives.

Comment: Actually, by default there don't seem to be internet access on Android TV emulators.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue w/ Android TV emulators: https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/issues/50